# Dúvida sobre getSource() instanceof

Tags: java, swing, tipagem, awt

**Instanceof** é um operador binário que testa se um objeto é o subtipo de um determinado tipo.
Ex:

```
Object fonte = e.getSource();
if (fonte instanceof JButton){
...
}
```

Se **getSource()** retornou informações de um **JButton** o resultado da expressão será **true**.

O que não entendo é o por que do retorno da expressão ser verdadeiro, já que o retorno do **getSource()** é do tipo objeto, então todo objeto é subtipo de **JButton?** Caso eu tenha:

```
Object fonte = e.getSource();
if (fonte instanceof JLabel){
...
}
```

Supondo que o **getSource()** agora retorne informações sobre um **JLabel**, como acontece a diferenciação já que **fonte** é sempre do tipo **Object**? **Instanceof** vai testar o contéudo de **fonte**?

Comment: Isso se chama `polimorfismo`. E todo objeto implicitamente herda de `Object`. Entendendo polimorfismo, respondera sua dúvida

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isso se chama polimorfismo. E todo objeto implicitamente herda de Object. Entendendo polimorfismo, respondera sua dúvida.

Não entrando em detalhes sobre polimorfismo,
como ja sabemos que todo objeto herda de Object,
então por polimorfismo um objeto do tipo `Object` pode receber(guardar referencia) de qualquer outro objeto, e é isso que está acontecendo.

E quando você faz a verificação com `instanceof` a jvm em tempo de execução verifica a classe do objeto que está sendo verificada.(ou seja, verifica qual classe foi instanciado esse objeto, se foi instanciada como JButton, JList, etc.)